# Android - ImageView Image Boundaries Bidder then Image

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, android-imageview

I am very very new to developing with Android on Eclipse.

I am making a basic relative layout and have a title, welcome msg, image, final text. in portrait mode.

The image seems to be the issue. When I am in a 2.7" screen the view bounds extend to the left and the right which is fine as there is nothing there. However if I move to a 7" or 10" view the image bounds extend up and down which pushes the text on top up and on the bottom down. So now there is a rather large chunk of white space.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzdpF.jpg this is the image when in 7-10" portrait (see the blue bounds pushing text away)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4pMa.jpg this is the image when in 2.7" and now the bound push to the left and right but don't cause any issues.

Optimally I would like for the image to just be always within those bounds. Below is all the xml involved. No java was changed. Appreciate any help. Thanks. A heads up if I change it to fitxy it stretches the image.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cs.play.quotably.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fdr"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/fdr" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/quote1"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any and all help!!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this one.
change the width and height to 30dp and it is not a fixed value.
just try different values like 40dp and 50dp.
and once you satisfy test it on both devices.
it should work

```js
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fdr"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/fdr" />
```